# Angular 2 Kendo grid not supporting odata v4

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, odata

I did try server side filtering using angular 2 kendo grid with odata v4 but it showing 'contains' keyword not supporting.  new version using 'substringof' instead of 'contains' how can i solve this issue

Comment: have you found a solution on this? i'm facing the same problem...

Comment: Yes actually i was using wrong version not V4 and check the Web ApiConfig also

Answer (score 0):

Install Odata V4 and configure WebApiConfig.cs

```
 ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
                var customer = builder.EntitySet<CustomerModel>("CustomerSearch");

                config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
                  routeName: "odata",
                  routePrefix: "odata",
                  model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

'CustomerModel' is my model to return 
"CustomerSearch" controller name

**Odata Controller**

```
 [EnableQuery]
    public class CustomerSearchController : ODataController
    {

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<CustomerModel> Get()
        {
            CustomerModelResponse list = new CustomerModelResponse();
            try
            {
                list = CustomerBL.GetCustomer(0);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            return list.CustomerList.AsQueryable();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We use OData v3.

What I did is i regex the queryString if it has a contains() and then replace it with substringof()

Here is an example:

```
  let queryString = toODataString(state);
  const regex = /(contains(([^)]+)\)))/;
  queryString = _.replace(queryString, regex, `substringof('${filter.value}', ${filter.field})`);
```

I'm using lodash here but i should also work with the string.replace function